# Conditional Table

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, infinite-loop

I have following :

```
SeedRandom[2]
Table[Table[RandomInteger[100, {100, 10}][[r, s]] == x[r + s], {r, 1, 10}], {s,1,10}]
```

How can I set condition inside Tables?Such as if `r>s` set 40 times of `x` value?Or something like this ?I want to have many of those conditions inside two tables?

Any suggestion for using other commands?

Comment: not really answering your question, but avoiding `Table`(you could specify `r` and `s` in the same table anyway), you could generate the `RandomInteger` directly and apply the condition on the pairs, e.g. like: `If[#1 > #2, "a", "b"] & @@@ RandomInteger[100, {100, 2}]`

Comment: Where is `x` defined in your code??

Comment: @PinguinDirk thanks but instead of Random I have real data .I just put that random to show some number.

Comment: @Nasser it variable.I need it that way.for example I need x[12] multiply to two cause in 9+3, we have 9>3.

Comment: Ok, I see, I thought it was a list at first.

Comment: I don't get the question. You can use `If`-statements inside `Table` calls.

Comment: @Wizard yes I found it now as: Table evaluates If[i≥j, a++, 0] but what if I need more if inside table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table works much like `Do` -- you can have any number of statements inside. For instance:

```
Table[r = 100; statement1; statement2; RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

Here the `r = 100` doesn't do anything, and the statements can be anything -- just separate them with a semicolon. The final term (in this case a `RandomReal`) occurs without semicolon and is the thing that is returned in the `Table`.

Comment: Many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not all sure I grasp your question, but perhaps you're looking for `MapIndexed`.

```
SeedRandom[2]; data = RandomInteger[100, {5, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{92, 57, 22}, {84, 63, 1}, {81, 96, 19}, {38, 67, 68}}
> ```

```
MapIndexed[If[#2[[1]] > #2[[2]], 40 #1, #1] &, data, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{92, 57, 22}, {3360, 63, 1}, {3240, 3840, 19}, {1520, 2680, 2720}}
> ```